# OPENXML Drops Trailing CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-openxml

When I run this SQL in SSMS (all versions 2005-2014) the final select statement's Child column has data that is missing the final CHAR(13) and CHAR(10).  Is there a way to have OPENXML or it's WITH clause specify not to truncate these characters?

```
DECLARE @IDoc INT
DECLARE @SerializedEntity XML

CREATE TABLE #BadResultTable(doc XML)

INSERT INTO #BadResultTable(doc)
    SELECT NewXML=
     (SELECT Child='Please dont strip my carriage return' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
      FOR XML PATH('Parent'), TYPE, ELEMENTS XSINIL)

SET @SerializedEntity = (SELECT doc FROM #BadResultTable FOR XML PATH('Parent'), TYPE, ELEMENTS XSINIL)

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @IDoc OUTPUT, @SerializedEntity

/*PROBLEM HERE: The Child column is missing the training CHAR(13) and CHAR(10)*/
SELECT Child,ASCII(SUBSTRING(Child, LEN(Child), 1))
        FROM OPENXML(@IDoc, '/Parent', 2)
        WITH (Child NVARCHAR(MAX) '//Child/text()'
    )
```

Comment: CR / LF are whitespace in XML. Look for a way to preserve whitespace.

Comment: Thanks @John: are you suggesting that my only way out here is to use some other markers for chr(13) and chr(10) and do string replace?

Comment: Thanks John you're right, XQuery was the right way to go - it worked!  If you move your comment down to an answer I'll pad your stats! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a way to get OPENXML to do that.

Why not just use XQuery since you've already got the data in an XML column? The CR+LF are present in the XML column. It's only OPENXML that destroys them.